# Losing the original text when doing tostring()

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, tostring

## I have a json object with one of the keys being:

```
"transcript": "The universe is bustling with matter and energy. Even in the vast apparent emptiness of intergalactic space, there's one hydrogen atom per cubic meter. That's not the mention a barrage of particles and electromagnetic radiation passing every which way from stars, galaxies, and into black holes. There's even radiation left over from the Big Bang...
```

## Loading the dataframe:

```
#initialize dataframe for the universe transcript 

dfJson = pd.read_json('test1.json')
```

Here's my code for trying to extract it.

```
dfJsonTranscript = dfJson.get('transcript').to_string()
pprint.pprint(dfJsonTranscript)

text_file = open("sample.txt", "wt")
n = text_file.write(dfJsonTranscript)
text_file.close()
```

## My Output

```
0      The universe is bustling with matter and energ...
1      The universe is bustling with matter and energ...
2      The universe is bustling with matter and energ...
3      The universe is bustling with matter and energ...
4      The universe is bustling with matter and energ...
5      The universe is bustling with matter and energ...
6      The universe is bustling with matter and energ...
7      The universe is bustling with matter and energ...
8      The universe is bustling with matter and energ...
```

## Original JSON:

```
"transcript": "The universe is bustling with matter and energy. Even in the vast apparent emptiness of intergalactic space, there's one hydrogen atom per cubic meter. That's not the mention a barrage of particles and electromagnetic radiation passing every which way from stars, galaxies, and into black holes. There's even radiation left over from the Big Bang... universe. ",
  "words": [
    {
      "alignedWord": "the",
      "case": "success",
      "end": 6.31,
      "endOffset": 3,
      "phones": [
        {
          "duration": 0.09,
          "phone": "dh_B"
        },
        {
          "duration": 0.05,
          "phone": "iy_E"
        }
      ],
      "start": 6.17,
      "startOffset": 0,
      "word": "The"
    },
    {
      "alignedWord": "universe",
      "case": "success",
      "end": 6.83,
      "endOffset": 12,
      "phones": [
        {
          "duration": 0.08,
          "phone": "y_B"
        },
```

**Why am I losing the original value of my key when running the toString() method on it. Am I losing it because I am turning it into a dataframe via pandas?**

Comment: JSON is a serialization format. By the time you import it into python or into a dataframe, it isn't JSON any more. Whatever you did to create `dfJson` painted that single line into a column called "transcript". We would need a better sample of the original json (shorting sentence would be good!) and how you put it into the dataframe.

Comment: @tdelaney I've updated the question to provide more information for troubleshooting. Thank you for your input

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is. Try `print(dfJson)` and you'll see you have a 2 column dataframe. The first column is "The universe is bustling..." over and over and the second column is each instance of the `dict` in the "words" list. You take the entire "transcript" column and call `tostring` so you get the text repeated over and over again. I doubt that is what you want. If you just want the text in "transcript" then you shouldn't be using pandas DataFrame at all. Just use `json.load` to read the file.